# Speed up query for name matching in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, matching

I am trying to conduct a name search in a large address table with mio. of rows. I have a table address and a table admin where coordinates from administrative levels 1 to 4 can be found. Whenever I find all the administrative levels in my address field in table address, I want to update the coordinates from the address table with coordinates from the admin table.
I also want to do this for different combinations of administrative levels. For example, I created a table admin1_2 or admin1_3 where only administrative levels 1 and 2 or 1 and 3 appear. In order to make sure that I have unique coordinates for each admin pair, I calculated average coordinates by the respective admin levels considered.
I want to implement the matching step-by-step, starting with all admin levels, then to combinations of 3 different levels (if matching on all levels has not been succesful), then 2, and finally only admin1, or admin2, or ...

The problem is that the query is very slow. It takes more then 24h for all admin levels and about the same amount of time for 3 levels. Given that I have a bunch of different combinations, it will take ages. I tried to index the columns appropriately, but do not have enough knowledge to understand the query plan and how to make the query faster.
Any help is appreciated. Please see the code and the query plan below.

```
create index country_idx on adress(country);
create index address_idx on address using GIN (address_field gin_trgm_ops);
update address t1 set
admin1 = t.admin1,
admin2 = t.admin2,
admin3 = t.admin3,
admin4 = t.admin4
postal_code = t.postal_code,
lat = t.lat,
lng = t.lng from (
select * from admin) t
where t1.country = t.country
and t1.address_field like '%' || t.admin1 || '%' --looks whether city name from admin shows up in address_field in t1
and t1.address_field like '%' || t.admin2 || '%'
and t1.address_field like '%' || t.admin3 || '%'
and t1.address_field like '%' || t.admin4 || '%'
;

Update on address t1  (cost=0.17..4069793.89 rows=134 width=203)"
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.17..4069793.89 rows=134 width=203)"
        ->  Seq Scan on admin  (cost=0.00..24314.49 rows=958249     width=81)"
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on address t1  (cost=0.17..4.21 rows=1 width=73)"
              Recheck Cond: ((address_field ~~ (('%'::text || admin.admin1) || '%'::text)) AND (address_field ~~ (('%'::text || admin.admin2) || '%'::text)) AND (address_field ~~ (('%'::text || admin.admin3) || '%'::text)) AND (address_field ~~ (('%'::text || admin.admin4) || '%'::text)))"
              Filter: (admin.country = country_)"
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on address_idx  (cost=0.00..0.17 rows=1 width=0)"
                    Index Cond: ((address_field ~~ (('%'::text || admin.admin1) || '%'::text)) AND (address_field ~~ (('%'::text || admin.admin2) || '%'::text)) AND (address_field ~~ (('%'::text || admin.admin3) || '%'::text)) AND (address_field ~~ (('%'::text || admin.admin4) || '%'::text)))"
```

EDIT: The admin fields are indexed with GIN indexes. I was not able to improve performance.
Any further suggestions?

Comment: Add an index on country and all admin fields. Then try something like `UPDATE address t1 SET ... FROM admin t WHERE ...` (no need to select * from admin).

Comment: such as: create index admin1_idx on admin(admin1);

Comment: good. which kind of index do you recommend for the admin fields? the GIN?

Comment: I've only ever used the default (BTREE), not sure how others perform on a LIKE.

Comment: Check out this on how to improve the performance of `LIKE` using other index types: https://niallburkley.com/blog/index-columns-for-like-in-postgres/

Comment: It has been a while, but I am still trying... All admin fields are indexed with GIN indexes. I do not select* anymore. However, the query plan looks almost similar. Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** not just a "plain" explain